# How to port forward on "My" huawei modem (Minecraft Server)

Tags: port-forwarding, modem

I want to port forward for my Minecraft server. I've been trying to do this for **months**. I've literally tried everything. I literally don't know how to **configure** any of the stuff I've tried correctly. I would like someone to tell me **how to do it** and **how it works**. These are what I've tried:

- Disabled the firewall switch ( This is not a large server. Just for a few friends
- Creating a virtual server:
  [image: Virtual Server Box]
- Creating a special application:
  [image: Special Application Box]
- And messing with the LAN filter but I realised this won't matter, as well as the fact being that I've disabled firewall.

Comment: Virtual Server sounds like your best bet. WAN port is the port where your friends (from outside your house) to connect to. LAN IP address is the internal IP address of where your Minecraft server is located. LAN Port is the port number of the Minecraft server. As an example: If you want your friend to connect to your server at port 12345, and your minecraft server (internally) is on 192.168.0.123 on port 1212, you put WAN port 12345, LAN IP 192.168.0.123, LAN port 1212. Protocol TCP/UDP, status ON. And that should port-forward any request to your WAN IP:12345 to your internal minecraft server.

Comment: Ok... The default port for Minecraft is 25565 should I put that in both ports?

Comment: And I beleive that an internal minecraft server is a singleplayer world is it now?

Comment: I don't know as I don't play minecraft or ever run their server.. but you are correct, put port 25565 on both WAN port and LAN port. This way your friends can connect to the standard port (25565) and it will then port-forwarded internally into your LAN IP on port 25565.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good you at least found the router config. Now for the port forwarding itself.
Only for the virtual server list and it should do the job.

1. Get to know what your computer IP is. (type in cmd ipconfig and see
   ipv4)
2. Put that ip in the place Lan IP Address
3. Then fill in WAN port (this is the port your friends have to use to
   connect)
4. Then fill in Lan Port (this is the port of the server. by default
   25565)
5. Set status to On and save the config

For the name you can just fill in 'MC Server' or whatever you like.

Now go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ add semicollon and then the WAN Port.
e.x 33.123.123.123:wanport and give that to your friends to connect to.

To test if it works you can also go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and fill in the WAN port in the port field.

Now for the how does this all works part.

Your router sees the request of your friend and checks the port. It will see to what computer and port it has to forward your friend to because you've portforwarded it. Your minecraft host will be hosted on your interal IP and port for your computer. Because the router sees the open port it will connect your friend trough to your minecraft server.

Comment: Lol i got it sorted just before you told me, but this does answer the question. I understand it now. Six months worth of doing that lol.

Comment: And instead of my WAN port i just gave them my internal IP. I trust them with that but im changing it with noip.com right now.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket well at least now you know how to do it and how it works. What ports you use is all up to you since you can easily change it at this point.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Your internal IP is worthless for anyone outside your LAN. You're connected to the outside world using *only* your public (ie. WAN-side) IP, the one you can see on IP-checking websites. Your router joins these two networks (WAN and LAN) using Network Address Translation (NAT): it remembers which port on public IP corresponds to which port on which local IP. The only way to access this port on your machine from WAN is through your public IP and corresponding WAN port you have just configured.

Comment: Ah I understand. I tested this on a computer on the same network. I have yet to test for people being able to connect from the "outside"